# HTML/PHP inline update and delete for each row of a table

Tags: html, forms, crud

Having a bit of a problem with an inline 'update' button, where I am pulling data from a mysql table (done), presenting that data to the screen using 'foreach' (done) and have a update and delete button on each line that POSTs the correct button 'name' and ID of the user (done).

However what the $_POST array isnt parsing is the correct data with the row information....  It does parse Changes to the bottom row, but if you change another row, it just parses the last row again....

```
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit" />
    <pre></pre>
    <?php print_r($_POST);?>
    <?php 
    echo '<table class="table table-condensed">';
    echo '<thead><tr><th style="width: 15%">Name</th><th style="width: 25%">Login</th><th style="width: 25%">Email</th><th style="width: 7%">Role</th><th style="width: 7%">Group</th><th style="width: 15%">LoftID</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
        foreach($users as $person){
             echo '<tr>';
             echo '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="'.$person['id'].'" placeholder="Name" value="'.$person['name'].'"/></td>';
             echo '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="login" id="'.$person['id'].'" placeholder="Login" value="'.$person['login'].'"/></td>';
             echo '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mail" id="'.$person['id'].'" placeholder="Mail" value="'.$person['mail'].'"/></td>';
             echo '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="role" id="'.$person['id'].'" placeholder="Role" value="'.$person['role'].'"/></td>';
             echo '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="group" id="'.$person['id'].'" placeholder="Group" value="'.$person['group'].'"/></td>';
             echo '<td><select type="text" class="form-control" name="LoftID" id="'.$person['id'].'" placeholder="Loft">';
             foreach($lofts as $info) {
                 if($info['id']==$person['LoftID']){
                      echo '<option value='.$info["id"].' selected>'.$info["name"].'</option>';
                 }
                 else{
                      echo '<option value='.$info["id"].'>'.$info["name"].'</option>';    
                 }
             }
             echo '</select></td>';
             echo '<td><button type="submit" name="update" value="'.$person['id'].'" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button></td>';
             echo '<td><button type="submit" name="delete" value="'.$person['id'].'" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button></td>';
             echo '</tr>';
          }   
          echo '</tbody></table>';
    ?>
    </div>
    </form>
```

What I need is for to allow me to pull the data from the $_POST so I can then throw it back into the database as an update based on the ID, which I believe I can do, as I have done that already in my code....

I would really like to do this without the need to display another page with the data on it to update....

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is variable $lofts? I don't see where it comes from.. And to modify the row using button you must using ajax with data-id information, not a value.

Comment: $lofts is an Array that holds the loftID and LoftName.  LoftID is in the main data so that is used to put a readable name in the input box

Comment: You must specify that before : $lofts=??? then foreach($lofts as $info) {.  Please try open your code on Firefox and right click and View page source. You can see if any php error on the page.

Comment: Thanks,  Yes that is all defined...  As I have said the render of the data from the database is correct and works fine....  What is not working is the POST back to the page with the correct ROW data.  It DOES sent the correct, button name and button ID, but it only sends the lasts rows worth of data...  If the last row is changed then it sends that correctly, but only the last row.  If you change any other rows data, then the POST just sends the last row as it was written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Ajax for doing that job without reloading the page or go to another page with parameter. And remember that button doesn't has value like input. Use data-id or data-pid or what ever you like. And put a class name for example 'updateBtn' to identify the button.

```
echo '<td><button type="button" data-pid="'.$person['id'].'" class="btn btn-primary updateBtn">Update</button></td>';

    <script>  
        $('.updateBtn').on('click', function() { 
        var pid = $(this).data('pid'); console.log(pid); // see the result in console
        var pid = parseInt(pid);  // change to int
        $.ajax({
                url: '/ajax/update-data/index.php', // specify folder and file name
                data: { pid : pid },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {                                  
                if(response.status == 'success') {  

                   // do something to the html code to show the successful update
                return false;
                }   
               if(response.status == 'fail') {  

                   // do something to the html code to show the fail update
                return false;
                }   
              }   
           });        
        });
    </script>
```

Ajax file :

```
<?php

  function response ($status) { 
      header("Content-Type:application/json");
      $response['status'] = $status;
      $json_response = json_encode($response);
      echo $json_response;
  }

if($_POST) {

$pid = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pid', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); 

    if($pid) {

        $done = // do php to chage update. You can refer to class or direct php mysql update

         if($done) {
          response ('success');
         }else{
          response ("fail");         
         }

    }else{
    response ("parameter fail");    

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks...  I dont mind reloading the page...  The submit goes back into the page, but I need it to also transmit the $_POST variables from the form, if that makes sense..  I have other pages working this way, but just cant get the multiple update buttons to 'POST' the right ROW of data.  Fairly sure its an ID or NAME issue??

Answer (score 0):

OK so I think I have found the answer, and have included the following;

```
echo '<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">';
```

Just under the first `foreach` statement, so that each row is its own form element.

Does anyone see any issues with doing it this way??  The data will always be quite limited and likely to never be more than 10s of rows.

Kind regards and thanks for all the help